# Regex array python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I know there is plenty of info about regex available but I can’t figure it out somehow.

I have an `array1 = ['\n 1.979   \n, \n 1.799   \n']` which looks like this but the numbers vary but are always in this format so the `regex = re.compile(r'\d.\d\d\d')` which matches perfectly in notepad++ but doesn’t seems to work in python.

```
import re 
regex = re.compile(r'\d.\d\d\d')
filteredarray= [i for i in array1 if regex.match(i)]

print(filteredarray)
```

what am I missing?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: That is a single string in a list (of length 1). The numbers are not of the format you have posted as there are spaces and newlines in the string. Are you sure you have Notepad++ in Regex mode and not Extended mode?

Comment: Read the documentation for `match` again.

Comment: Use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) instead.

Comment: To create an array of the number strings: `regex.findall(array1[0])`

Comment: @Thefourthbird TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Comment: Use it on your pattern: `regex.search(i)`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall(expression, string)` to find the required values and convert it into list.

The correct regular expression for your requirement is `\d\.?\d{3}` or you can also use `\d\.\d\d\d`

```
import re

array1 = ['\n 1.979   \n, \n 1.799   \n']

filteredarray = []
for i in array1:
    filteredarray.extend(re.findall('\d\.?\d{3}', i))

print(filteredarray)
```

Comment: thank you but why was my regex wrong it also matched fully on regex101

Comment: Yours also right, but `[i for i in array1 if regex.match(i)]` this part is wrong.
you are assigning the value in array that represents 'i'. As you are assigning the same value in array1, you are getting the same value in array

Comment: @Dinesh Sounds like you already forgot why you escaped their dot.

Comment: I've not escaped the dot present in the string.

Comment: Yes you did (in the regex string).

Comment: yeah, sorry. I've escaped the dot  as `.` must be present in the decimal format

Answer (score 0):

I think that your pattern `\d.\d\d\d` is not at [start](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match) of `\n 1.979   \n, \n 1.799   \n`. You just replace `\d.\d\d\d` by `^[\s\S]+\d.\d\d\d`.

**Details**:

- `^`: start of string
- `[\s\S]+`: matches any characters, including line breaks.

I also tried test result on python.

```
import re
array1 = ['\n 1.979   \n, \n 1.799   \n']
regex = re.compile(r'^[\s\S]+\d.\d\d\d')

filteredarray= [i for i in array1 if regex.match(i)]

print(filteredarray)
```

Result.

```
['\n 1.979   \n, \n 1.799   \n']
```